# Работа PHP + MySQL в WebView (Android)

Tags: php, java, android, mysql, webview

Столкнулся с таким вопросом - есть ли какие-либо готовые модули (либо какая-либо документация) относительно того, как внутри приложения (где основное - это WebView) запустить локальный сервер для исполнения PHP-скриптов и доступом к локальной БД? Кеширование в локальном хранилище я сделал, но это статика. Хочется реализовать исполнение скриптов на стороне самого устройства.

Буду благодарен за любую информацию!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571911/running-amp-apache-mysql-php-on-android